# React server mismatches: Prop `className` did not match

Tags: next.js, styled-components

If you're using styled components and keep getting errors in development mode use the settings below to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .babelrc file in your root folder and add the following:

```
{ "presets": [ "next/babel" ], "plugins": [ [ "styled-components", { "ssr": true } ] ] }
```